In browser, characters show up as hex box
I've tried installing fonts like Tibetan machine, Arial family, Open Sans, etc. I've also checked my locale and it's already set to UTF-8. I don't know what to do now. Please help. Thank you.
This is what it looks like:


I've found a solution to my problem! Installing unifont solves this problem.
For anyone having this problem:
sudo apt install unifont
